# How to loop variable creation and str_replace dynamically in R

Tags: r

I am trying to parse multiple columns into each of their components.  However the number of components varies across the columns.  Specifically, suppose the following df:

```
id  X1.startAll                                        X2.startAll          
1   ["1555726884484","1555727530298","1555727532509"]  
2                                                      ["1555735159384","1555735161545"]
3   ["1555730029709"]
4   ["1555735159384","1555735161545"]
5
6                                                      ["1555735159384","1555735161545"]
```

now I have 40 of these columns (and another 120 very similar ones, to which I aim to generalize the process) and many more rows.  I can do the first column quite simply using the following:

```
df1$X1.startAll1 <- str_replace(df1$X1.startAll, "\\[\"([0-9]+)\",*\"*([0-9]*)\"*,*\"*([0-9]*)\"*\\]", "\\1")

df1$X1.startAll2 <- str_replace(df1$X1.startAll, "\\[\"([0-9]+)\",*\"*([0-9]*)\"*,*\"*([0-9]*)\"*\\]", "\\2")

df1$X1.startAll3 <- str_replace(df1$X1.startAll, "\\[\"([0-9]+)\",*\"*([0-9]*)\"*,*\"*([0-9]*)\"*\\]", "\\3")
```

which yields my desired result:

```
id  X1.startAll                                        X1.startAll1    X1.startAll2   X1.startAll3    
1   ["1555726884484","1555727530298","1555727532509"]  1555726884484   1555727530298  1555727532509
2                                                      
3   ["1555730029709"]                                  1555730029709
4   ["1555735159384","1555735161545"]                  1555735159384   1555735161545
5
6
```

However, I have to do this for many columns and for many different 'array' lengths within each of these.

I have tried automating this using a for loop, however, I (1) can't figure out how to read the right number of iterations (i.e. the max the number of components in the startAll column), (2) dynamically create the variables, (3) nor how to update the string extraction dynamically ("\\i").

Any and all help on looping this process would help a lot!

Edit 2: below is a copy-pasteable sample of the data:

```
structure(list(X1.startAll = list(NA, NA, NA, NA, c(1555726884484, 
1555727530298, 1555727532509), NA, NA, c(1555735159384, 1555735161545
), NA, NA, NA, 1555730029709, NA, NA, NA, c(1555728423843, 1555728561054, 
1555728586917), c(1555725657389, 1555725657827), c(1555703810672, 
1555703823206, 1555703848659), NA, NA), X2.startAll = list(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, c(1555727541885, 1555727786959, 1555727897893
    ), NA, NA, 1555735262052, c(1555737694350, 1555737696711), 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X3.startAll = list(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, c(1555727920770, 1555728230065, 1555728843391
    ), NA, NA, c(1555735331144, 1555735452321, 1555735457305), 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X4.startAll = list(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1555728854666, NA, NA, 1555735589629, 1555738374484, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X5.startAll = list(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, c(1555728949327, 1555728988444), NA, NA, 
    c(1555735646258, 1555735912372, 1555735914267, 1555736071856, 
    1555736074184, 1555736093411, 1555736124826, 1555736238538, 
    1555736248889, 1555736576754, 1555736620915, 1555736874386, 
    1555737698921, 1555737777400, 1555737966562, 1555738152090, 
    1555738354075, 1555738700232, 1555738703134, 1555738716736
    ), 1555738415269, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X6.startAll = list(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1555729661240, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1555738960285, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), X7.startAll = list(NA, NA, NA, NA, c(1555730266934, 
1555730356654, 1555730533798, 1555730535289), NA, c(1555732523945, 
1555733415340, 1555733477452, 1555733748200, 1555734007271, 1555734286685, 
1555734288597), NA, c(1555739871726, 1555740315324, 1555740328252, 
1555740329835, 1555740538272, 1555741140561, 1555741143555, 1555741152932
), c(1555743562826, 1555743566386, 1555743593201), NA, NA, NA, 
    c(1555727969354, 1555727985539, 1555728064237, 1555738166838, 
    1555826735910), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X8.startAll = list(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks like json. Might be easier to use a json-parsing package upstream in your workflow.

Comment: If you do want help from where you are, it would be nice of you to provide the input in a copy/pasteable format, `dput(df)` (or `dput(droplevels(head(df)))` if you have `factor` columns and more rows)

Comment: Hi @Gregor, these are all arrays I created in javascript and actually have not used a json parsing package before but sounds interesting.  I just had a quick look at jsonlite and tried to use flatten, but the arrays in these columns are not data frames themselves.  I updated the question to include a copy pasteable version!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't have a full answer (and need to do work), but as a start, define `my_parser = function(x) {if (x == "") return(NA); as.numeric(jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = x))}`, and then `df[] = lapply(df, lapply, parser)` give a pretty good start. Puts numeric vectors instead of json strings in each column, just need to separate them out from there.

Comment: Hi @Gregor, it tells me that my variables aren't JSON string, url or file.  I also couldn't just simply turn them to numeric using standard ```as.numeric(as.character())``` approach.  I think seperating them is not hard using regex as I did with ```str_replace()```, however, looping that correctly seems hard.   But, maybe if they are numeric there is an even easier way that I can't see right.  Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, forgot a step. The Error is because you're starting with factors, not characters.  Do this first: `df[] = lapply(df, as.character)`  and my code will run. (This will probably help with other methods as well.)

Comment: Thank you!  This worked @Gregor.  I now have an updated data structure.  I edited my post for the resulting updated data structure.

Comment: I was just trying to move this to a chat but apparently I can't.  @Gregor, how do you suggest we proceed from here?